# Linux. Issues with changing keyboard layout. Is there is a way to change keydown to keyup trigger?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, hotkeys

I've faced the following problem on Linux: when I use alt+shift for changing keyboard layout it's prevented me when I'm working in emacs. I've tried to switch to super+space key combination but every time I change layout right panel always appear (I'm using MX Linux). In general, such behavior breaks a lot of hotkeys in different apps (for ex. firefox). Is there exist a common solution to solve this issue? It seems that it will be a solution if I can change the triggering of the system hotkeys on keyup instead of keydown. I've tried to find such a solution, but my searches were not succeeded.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use native xorg keyboard switching layout with `setxkbmap`. e.g. `setxkbmap us,hu ,102_qwerty_dot_dead -option grp:alt_shift_toggle,numpad:microsoft`

Answer (score 0):

OK. I found a solution. The problem is related to the XOrg [bug](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=865). The bug reported in 2004. I found a [patch](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/keyboard-layout-switching-problems-and-poll/2876/40) to fix this issue:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nrbrtx/xorg-hotkeys
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After that, all hotkeys in all softwares will work correctly, even if they contain switch layout combination